# Remove the "p." abbreviation in the result of the \cite command (bilatex)

Tags: biblatex

If I use for example the command `\cite[X.2]{book}` with `X.2` as optional argument, I get `[p. X.2,BOOK]` as a result (where `BOOK` stands for the reference number of the `book` reference). Because `X.2` stands for a chapter, rather then page number, I would of course like to get rid of the "p.". Because I rather rarely refer to pages, I would like to have this behaviour by default. I can probably change it using an optional argument of `\usepackage{biblatex}`. Which one?

Now I have in my preamble:
`\usepackage[doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,backref=true]{biblatex}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simplly have to add the following line in the preamble

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,backref=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[X.2]{angenendt}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for any reason, you want the page abbreviation in one citation, use the commands `\pno` to print `p.` and `\ppno` to print `pp.`, for example `\cite[\ppno~X.2]{angenendt}`.

Comment: +1 You might want to note that one still can use `\pno` and `\ppno` to force page numbers if need be.

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected. And sorry that it was you who had to supply the MWE.

Comment: @wondering You're welcome. And no problems for the MWE. The question was quite clear even without it :)